# SQL Server Witness Server Alternative Approach

Tags: sql-server, sql, mirroring, database-mirroring

I have the setup below:

3 Database Servers 1 DR Database Server 1 Domain Controller 1 DR Domain Controller

Currently I have the DR domain controller acting as the mirroring witness for the 3 Database server but I just had a network issue on the DR Domain controller which caused a database failover.

Is there a different approach I could setup so my databases don't failover when there is an issue with the witness server on DR?

Comment: YOu mean besides getting more hardware? Because, given mirroring with wittness needs 3 instances, there is not exactly a lot of room with only 3 servers.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  I have 6 servers all running an instance of MS SQL Server.

Comment: Not wha you say. WIthin the limitation of the question there is nothing you can do. We do not care about information you withhold.

Comment: 3 Database Servers 1 DR Database Server 1 Domain Controller 1 DR Domain Controller = 6 Servers....